# Stripe.applePay.checkAvailability returns false in mobile Safari

Tags: stripe-payments, applepay

Following the stripe docs, I am trying to setup Apple Pay on web.

But the function provided by Stripe returns avaiability as false.

```
Stripe.applePay.checkAvailability(function(available) {
  if (available) {
    document.getElementById('apple-pay-button').style.display = 'block';
  } else {
    document.getElementById('apple-pay-button').style.display = 'none';
  }
});
```

I am testing in dev environment, and connecting to the server with ngrok on my mobile safari.

Anyone has experience with getting it to work?

**Update**:

so my last attempt was

- using a 2016 macbook with fingerprint reader (so I don't need to do handoff)
- in safari, ngrok, latest MacOS...
- `checkAvailability` is getting invoked and `available` returns `false`
- The only thing is stripe API, we're still on an old API because there are breaking changes and we haven't made the attempt to upgrade yet
- but, we had successfully made apple pay work with the api version we are using.

Comment: Are you logged into your iTunes Connect Sandbox Account?  If you're not, this will always happen.

Comment: @korben yep, but it's buggy. not returning true all the time.

Comment: maybe worth filing with Apple Pay Developer Support.  The checkAvailability() method actually just wraps Apple Pay JS and doesn't add any additional logic, afaik.  Do you see the same results using Apple Pay JS alone?

Comment: @korben I didn't try the Apple Pay JS alone. But I'll do a little more digging. Will post anything I found here.

Comment: I had similar issues with this but with `ApplePaySession` directly, not via Stripe. Some observations I had at the time are here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39728878/starting-with-apple-pay-on-the-web/40004697#40004697

Comment: @MartinCostello thanks a lot for that!! I will test it out when I get a chance

Answer (score 2):

Some debugging tips that may help developers landing here trying to get Apple Pay and Stripe to work:

- Ensure the device's regional settings are set to an Apple Pay supported country (US, UK, or Canada at time of writing)
- Leave the browser dev tools console open during development as instructive error messages are sometimes logged there by the 3rd party libraries. Review and debug all errors logged in the console.
- Check the page is being served over HTTPS (required by Apple Pay). Consider using a proxying service such as fwd/ngrok/etc. in your development environment.
- Confirm the `checkAvailability` function is running. Try putting a `alert('inside checkAvailability');` call as the first line of the callback function.
- Confirm the value of `available` is as expected, again using `alert(...)`.
- Check `stripe.js` is included in the page before using any `Stripe.applePay` functionality.
- Check Stripe API keys are set correctly for the environment (test or production)
- Update to latest iOS and/or macOS to ensure the Safari version supports Apple Pay.